# Unable to send french text in proper format from textarea in PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i am using PHPmailer for sending email to my webmail. I am trying to send some french text but it is not converting the special characters. I am trying to enter text is this

Âgée de 40 ans et mère de deux enfants, Alessandra est experte en communication. À la base, elle détient une formation de juriste, de l'université Assas-Paris II. Elle est devenu consultante règlementée en immigration canadienne.

and it is coming to my webmail as

Ã‚gÃ©e de 40 ans et mÃ¨re de deux enfants, Alessandra est experte en communication. Ã€ la base, elle dÃ©tient une formation de juriste, de l'universitÃ© Assas-Paris II. Elle est devenu consultante rÃ¨glementÃ©e en immigration canadienne.

And here is my PHPMailer function:

> $mail = new PHPMailer;
>
> ```
>                           $mail->isSMTP();                     
>
>                           $mail->Host = "mail.vbought.com";
>
>                           $mail->Port = 26;
>
>                           $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
>
>
>                           $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
>
>                           $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
>
>                           $mail->addAddress('test@vbought.com', 'FOCUS CANADA');
>
>                           $mail->isHTML(true);   
>                           $mail->Subject = $subject_admin;
>                           $mail->Body    = $body;
>
>                           $mail->AddAttachment($tmpName, $fileName);
>
>                           if (!$mail->send()) {
>                               echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
>                           }
> ```

And my $body near with MESSAGE POST is:

$body .="**email** :-".$_POST['email']."";

```
                            $body .="<tr><td><b>phone</b> :-</td><td>".$_POST['phone']."</td></tr>";


                            $body .="<tr><td><b>Message</b> :-</td><td>".strtr($_POST['message'], array("\r\n" => '<br />', "\r" => '<br />', "\n" => '<br />'))."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Did you Tried `$mail->setHeader("charset:UTF-8");`.

Comment: Is there any specific place i should enter this? As i tried enter this. But this seems like stoping my page to process properly.

Comment: Don't set the header yourself, you'll just confuse things. Do what @Athipatla said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use charset setting for the mailer. `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` That will support some languages or you can use mb_detect_encoding and mb_convert_encoding on body text.